# CSS: display:table floating when add content

Tags: html, css

I have to implement this content:

```
<div class="content">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="cell">&nbsp;</div>
        <div class="cell" id = "up_lft"></div>
        <div class="cell" id = "up_rgh"></div>
        <div class="cell"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="cell">&nbsp;</div>
        <div class="cell" id = "dwn_lft"></div>
        <div class="cell" id = "dwn_rgh"></div>
        <div class="cell">&nbsp;</div>

    </div>
</div>
```

and the CSS

```
.content{
        display: table;
        margin-top:22px;
        width:100%; 
}

.row {
    display: table-row;
    width:100%;
 }

.cell {
    display: table-cell;
    width:auto;
    vertical-align:top;
}

#up_lft{
    width:100px;
    min-width:100px;
    height:125px;
    background-color:#8E9090;
    outline: 1px solid white;
}

#up_rgh{
    width:100px;
    min-width:100px;
    height:125px;
    background-color:#8E9090;
    outline: 1px solid white;
}

#dwn_lft{
    width:100px;
    min-width:100px;
    height:125px;
    background-color: #394249;
    outline: 1px solid white;


}

#dwn_rgh{
    width:100px;
    min-width:100px;
    height:125px;
    background-color:#872434;
    outline: 1px solid white;
}
```

on fiddle here:
http://jsfiddle.net/reJ7e/

I choose css display:table only because i need those boxes to stay on the center of the page no matter of screen resolution. I also need to add something after the bottom right div (a small height div that extends itself to the margin right screen and having a background image)

The problem is that if i try to put anything else but   in that div, all design is moving to the left. messy.
Any suggestions please? I am open to change the css display: table - but i don't know how to do it (all 4 boxes stay center)
Note that i also have a header with a menu having the same width above those boxex

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid display table and use position: absolute and also transforming the origin point of the element to make it exactly in the middle of the page:

```
position: absolute;

transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
transform: -webkit-translate(-50%, -50%);
transform: -moz-translate(-50%, -50%);
transform: -ms-translate(-50%, -50%);

top: 50%;
left: 50%;
```

Any element given this style will stay at the center of the page.. if you want it to stay at the center of the window just change from position: absolute to position: fixed.

[Here's an illustration fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/B36jC/)

Comment: You can also review these articles: http://fribly.com/2014/02/20/complete-guide-centering-div/, http://fribly.com/2013/09/24/absolute-centering/